# Compare results in SQL #temptable but i receive wrong results, wrong approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for my noob SQL questions...

My goal is to compare the results of 2 queries. I need the records from query #1 (13000 records) that are not in the results of query #2 (12700 records).

For this purpose i created the first query:

```
SELECT projectnr INTO #temptbl 
FROM prproject P JOIN absences A ON p.projectnr = a.freetextfield_01
WHERE projectnr  LIKE 'CONL%'
```

Results gave me 13009 records in the #temptbl

My 2nd query must filter the existing records:

```
DELETE FROM #temptbl
WHERE projectnr in (
   SELECT freetextfield_01 
   FROM absences 
   WHERE TYPE = 7013 
   GROUP BY freetextfield_01)
```

The results of the query:

```
(SELECT freetextfield_01 
 FROM absences 
 WHERE TYPE = 7013 
 GROUP BY freetextfield_01)
```

returns 12715 records.

But in the complete query it removes all the 13009 records instead of the 12715 records.

Perhaps the creation of a temptable is not needed using some"not in" statement, but i don't know how to do that.

Thanks for the trouble of reading this :)

Comment: is projectnr duplicated in any rows? if so this may cause all rows to be deleted

Comment: Indeed, it was a duplicate record in the projectnr. I thought it was a unique number, but it wasn't. So also a SELECT DISTINCT on that one.

Answer (score 1):

First off... those GROUP BYs are unnecessary... use SELECT DISTINCT instead.

In theory you do not need a temp table. You could do all this with this query:

```
SELECT p.projectnr
FROM prproject p
JOIN absences  a ON p.projectnr = a.freetextfield_01
WHERE p.projectnr  LIKE 'CONL%' AND p.projectnr NOT IN (
  SELECT freetextfield_01 
  FROM absences 
  WHERE type = 7013 
)
```

Why is your second query deleting everything? I suppose that you have duplicate projectnr in your first query and that absences of type 7013 cover all the projectnr you have like CONL%. Without seeing the data this is a hard call.

Also... depending on how the 2 tables are related, it is possible you can simplify the query. How many absence rows do you have per project row? Is it a one-to-many relationship? Do you have projects without absences? Do you want to keep these or not in your result set?

Comment: Regarding the relation. There is indeed an one-to-many relationship between prproject and absences. I will insert an example of the returned data